# Deal with Activity Destroying and Memory leaks in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, ondestroy

In my app, I added several libraries that refer to activities, in particular the Ads library.

When I start the next activity, often the previous one would be destroyed, the `onDestroy` method call and the LeakCanary memory leak notification.

**How can I prevent my activity from being destroyed and how to handle that memory loss?**

Note: I'm using Tapdaq mediation

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share with us what you are doing? (in onDestroy and how you start the next activity)

Comment: Simple, I start next activity with `startActivity(intent)` method. In the next activity, When I show interstitial or Rewarded Ad, my previous activity destroyed automatically. When I come back to the previous activity, it start from the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to analyze, did you put any `finish()` after the `startActivity(intent)` method? If not you should try to override the `onBackPressed()` method and maybe create the activity again!